# Signature declaration changed on compilation

Tags: ocaml

When I try to compile my code, I get the following error

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
       ...
       Values do not match:
         val filter_map : ('b -> 'b option) -> 'b t -> 'b list
       is not included in
         val filter_map : ('b -> 'a option) -> 'b t -> 'a list
       File "set.ml", line 7, characters 2-55: Expected declaration
       File "treeSet.ml", line 105, characters 10-20: Actual declaration
```

However, my signature is actually declared as follows.

```
module type SetS = sig
  type 'a t

  val empty : 'a t
  val insert : 'a t -> 'a -> 'a t
  val contains : 'a t -> 'a -> bool
  val filter_map : ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a t -> 'b list
end
```

For some reason, the error I get when compiling shows a different type declaration than the one I have actually implemented. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the function implementation? OCaml is inferring that `'a` and `'b` have to be the same based on the implementation, so a signature where they can vary independently is not allowed. Please edit the question to show the implementation and I'd be happy to write an answer explaining where it gets that information.

Comment: Without seeing the code I would just comment that you can't make code more polymorphic than it really is by declaring it to be so. Most likely the compiler is right about the type :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Signature mismatch` means that the derived signature of a module differs from the specified signatures. E.g., suppose we want to write a module with the following signature,

```
module type Expected = sig
  val filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
end
```

and we write,

```
module Real : Expected = struct
  let filter = List.filter_map
end
```

The error message that we get will be,

```
Signature mismatch:
Modules do not match:
  sig val filter : 'a list -> f:('a -> 'b option) -> 'b list end
is not included in
  Expected
Values do not match:
  val filter : 'a list -> f:('a -> 'b option) -> 'b list
is not included in
  val filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

So the problem is that our proposed implementation of `filter` has type `'a list -> f:('a -> 'b option) -> 'b list` but what we really   wanted and expected for the type of `filter` is `('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list`. That is what the error message says.

Applying to your case, your implementation has the inferred type `('b -> 'b option) -> 'b t -> 'b list` which doesn't match with the required type `('b -> 'a option) -> 'b t -> 'a list`. Notice that your type is less general. It filters list without changing the type of the element. So it can only filter map `int list` to `int list`, `string list` to `string list` and so on, unlike the more generic implementation that is able to map `int list` to `string list`.

To rectify the problem, you need to carefully review your implementation. Make sure that you don't have branching instructions (like if/then/else, match) such that one branch returns an element or elements of the input list and the other branch returns the element or elements of the output list. To demonstrate this, consider the following implementation,

```
let rec filter_map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs -> match f x with
    | None -> xs
    | Some x -> x :: filter_map f xs
```

Here I made an error, by returning `xs`, the input list, when `f x` evaluates to `None`. The other branch, constructs the output list, so we got the types of input and output lists unified. In the correct implementation, you should recursively call `filter_map` in both branches,

```
let rec filter_map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs -> match f x with
    | None -> filter_map f xs
    | Some x -> x :: filter_map f xs
```